# Is it possible to write all console output to a variable in Dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging

I have deployed my flutter app and one user says that a certain part is not working. Therefore, I am interested in finding a way to write all output that usually gets dumped to the console to a string. I could then send this string to myself and use it to debug the problem.

Is there a way to subscribe to all console output? I found `runZoned(() => ...)` but this seems to only collect certain logs and especially no logs from other isolates.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, it's possible to capture all log output and then store it as a variable. In practice, it's a lot of work and will likely require elevated privileges to access the log stream from within the app itself (which might not even be possible on iOS without a rooted device).

However, I propose that you flip the equation - instead of retrieving the log output, capture your logs before they make it to the console in the first place.

This is where packages such as [logger](https://pub.dev/packages/logger) shine. By routing all of your print statements through a logging service, you can set up middleware that will capture your output on the way through the pipe. This way, you can store all of the output without having to mess with things like OS permissions and privileges.

```dart
final buffer = BufferOutput();
final logger = Logger(output: buffer);

class BufferOutput extends LogOutput {
  final lines = <String>[];

  @override
  void output(OutputEvent event) {
    lines.addAll(event.lines);
    for (var line in event.lines) {
      print(line);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
logger.v("This is verbose text");
logger.d("This is debug text");
logger.i("This is info text");
logger.w("This is warning text");
logger.e("This is error text");
logger.wtf("This is what-the-fudgestickles text");

print(buffer.lines);

// Output:
// ["This is verbose text","This is debug text","This is info text","This is warning text","This is error text","This is what-the-fudgestickles text"]
```

Note: This will work if you want to capture normal app logging output. If you want to automatically capture exceptional log output, you are better off using something like [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics) or [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) to capture and collate those error logs for you since, depending on the error, you can't depend on your app code to be able to run after the error happens anyway.

Comment: This seems like a great option, thank you. However, there is no way of retrieving the logs of packages, right?

Comment: @CaptainDario If packages print to the console (which they aren't supposed to if they were made properly), then no, this option would not capture that output.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I think this is a good approach when using solely flutter, but I am using a ffi (c++) library and something is wrong there. So I upvoted your answer but I am going to keep the question open if there maybe is a way to get all output.

Comment: @CaptainDario In that case, I'd suggest opening the question up to beyond the scope of Flutter and seek answers specifically for iOS and Android separately, since whatever solution you find will invariably be outside the scope of Flutter itself.